# get the information from Naver LINE API through http request

Tags: ajax

I have a question on the chat app, Naver LINE. There is an API that provides login authentication called LINE login.

I've follow the instructions on the documents and run the querystring and I got a callback URL that gives me the code look like this,

```
    https://sample.com/callback?code=b5fd32eacc791df&state=123abc
```

Now, the document says I need to use the code in a http request using post method. I got the following,

```
    XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.line.me/v1/oauth/accessToken/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

Below is the request I wrote,

```
$.ajax({
      url: "https://api.line.me/v1/oauth/accessToken/",
      type: "POST",
      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
      },
      crossDomain: true,
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (response) {
        var resp = JSON.parse(response)
        alert(resp.status);
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, state, error) {
        alert("error", xhr, status);
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(state);
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
```

data is the credentials I put in so LINE would pass me the user's information.

Is there anything I did wrong? If so, how can I fix this?

Thanks ahead.